# How to access a C array in random order ensuring that all elements are visited at most once

Tags: c, arrays, random

Say I have a very big array of 64 bit integers, say a million of them defined like this:

```
uint64_t myNumbers[1000000];
```

The challenge is how to access each of those elements randomly ensuring that each one is visited once. So for example I could simply use a for loop and iterate through this array and add up all the numbers to get a result (which would overflow, but that's not important).

What I would like to do is repeat that but accessing the elements in that array randomly so that I ultimately end up with the same result as I would have had for the normal iteration.

So how would I go about creating another array of pointers to the original array elements where when iterating through it, it accesses each element randomly. This doesn't have to be done in real time, and the time taken to set up the second array doesn't have to be fast.

Basically I can't think of a good way to generate a random array of pointers to the elements in the first array and could really use some insight from the experts :)

Comment: Bump the index with a value that is relatively prime to the array size. ( := does not share a divisor other than 1 with it)

Comment: You need to perform a *random shuffle* (look it up).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to generate a random permutation (either of an array of the indices, or of an array of pointers to the elements of the original array, or perhaps it would be acceptable to shuffle the original array itself, depending on your use-case).

A good way to generate a random permutation is called [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle):

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

If space and performance is not an issue, the first solution that come in my mind is: create an array of same size as the one to be accessed; when you generate a random index, put it in this new array if not present, otherwise increment it and check again

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array with numbers from `0` to the `length of the array`, then shuffle it and then iterate throught it using its elements as indexes.

```
void shuffle(int *shuffled, int lenght, int times)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int aux;

    j = k = 0;
    for(i=0;i<times;i++)
    {
        do
        {
            j=rand() % length;
            k=rand() % length;
        } while j==k;

        aux = shuffled[j];
        shuffled[j] = shuffled[k];
        suffled[k] = aux;
    }
}
```

Then, you can acces the elements in random order doing.

```
for(i=0;i<lenght;i++)
{
    myNumbers[shuffled[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define sz 100
uint64_t myNumbers[sz];
long ind[sz];
void shufle(long r){
    long pick,l,t;
    for(l=0;l<r;l++)ind[l]=l;
    l=r;
    while(--l>0){
        pick=((1LL*random())*l)/RAND_MAX;
        t=ind[l];
        ind[l]=ind[pick];
        ind[pick]=t;
    }
} 

main(){
    //tst;
    long i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)myNumbers[i]=i;
    shufle(10);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)printf("%ld %ld\n",i,myNumbers[ind[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use while loop and a counter, the pseudo code should be:

```
 uint64_t myNumbers[1000000];
 uint64_t visited[1000000];

 int counter = 0;
 while (counter!=1000000)
 {
  int r = random(0,1000000);
  if (visited.Contains(r))
      break;
  else
     {
      printf(myNumbers[r]); //the action to be performed on the numbers in your array
      visited.add(r);
      counter++;
      }
 }
```